# libgdx table-layout enter event fires excessively

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to add a sound that plays when the user hovers their mouse cursor over a button. The problem is if there is something inside the button, the sound plays twice: once when their cursor enters the button, and once when it enters (or exits) the thing inside the button. Is there some way I can make the enter event only fire when the cursor enters the button from the outside and not from the inside?

Example code:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    TextureAtlas atlas;
    Skin skin;
    Image img;
    Sound enterSound;
    Stage stage;
    Table table;
    Button button;

    public void create () {
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui.pack");
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin.json"), atlas);
        img = new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
        enterSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sound.wav"));

        stage = new Stage();
        table = new Table(skin);
        table.setFillParent(true);
        stage.addActor(table);

        button = new Button(skin);
        button.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                enterSound.play();
            }
        });
        button.add(img).size(64);
        table.add(button).size(128);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found similar problem with cells which contain element on which mouse-enter listened.. Event mouse enter has been triggering 3 times (2 times on parent cells and finally on element).

You could such trick:

```
// update in listener
button.addListener(new InputListener() {

            final Button thisButton = button;

            @Override
            public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
            if (currentMouseOveredButton == null || !currentMouseOveredButton.equals(thisButton)){  
                // mark button has made sound
                currentMouseOveredButton= thisButton;
                enterSound.play();
            }
        });

// somewhere in ui class
Button currentMouseOveredButton;
```